# Cordova plugins not work with Ionic

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building out an Ionic app in Angular and ave never been able to get plugins to work.

As an example, I have tried using the statusbar plugin as described here:

http://ionicframework.com/tutorials/fullscreen-apps/

But it still shows in my app. I tried:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

and then "cordova prepare", "ionic run ios" and still no luck.

The plugins I get listed when I type

```
$ cordova plugin list

com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.2 "Keyboard"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.10 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.11 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.7 "StatusBar"
```

I also am using Gulp. I have a folder with all my dev work in, and gulp moves and compiles it into a /dist folder from whence it is served. I'm pretty sure the plugins are moved across perfectly, is there anywhere I should check the references?

Any ideas if there is something you have to do in order to use Cordova plugins with Ionic?

Comment: Can you give more information about steps you follow. It meant to work with cordova. I am guessing your enviroment is wrong or you missing something so little. Is it work without adding plugin. Thnx

Comment: I have added a bit more info, is there any other info you could use to help diagnose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to this was that I had to add

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

to my page, just above my scripts.

Please be aware this file doesnt exist during development, it's injected at runtime... which is why I could solve it. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This issue has been plaguing me for that last week.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

***Additional solution if including cordova.js doesn't resolve the problem***

I have had the same issue, but `cordova.js` was already included in my `index.html`. `window.plugins` always has been undefined. Then I noticed that there is a `cordova_plugins.js` file inside the `platforms/ios/www` folder.

Here's what I did:

1. `$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-flashlight`
2. `$ cordova prepare`
3. added `<script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>` right after `cordova.js` inside `index.html`

After that I could access the `window.plugins` variable.

**HINT:** take a look into your `cordova_plugins.js` and be aware that some plugins are attached to `cordova.plugins` (e.g. Keyboard Plugin, see below) others are attached to `window.plugins` (e.g. Flashlight)

**For reference** - my cordova_plugins.js file looks like this

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/logger.js",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-console.logger",
        "clobbers": [
            "cordova.logger"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-console.console",
        "clobbers": [
            "console"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-device.device",
        "clobbers": [
            "device"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen.SplashScreen",
        "clobbers": [
            "navigator.splashscreen"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/www/statusbar.js",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-statusbar.statusbar",
        "clobbers": [
            "window.StatusBar"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/ios/keyboard.js",
        "id": "ionic-plugin-keyboard.keyboard",
        "clobbers": [
            "cordova.plugins.Keyboard"
        ],
        "runs": true
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-flashlight/www/Flashlight.js",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-flashlight.Flashlight",
        "clobbers": [
            "window.plugins.flashlight"
        ]
    }
];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.0.0",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-flashlight": "3.0.0"
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on Android and iPhone simulator and works correctly. Try this code:

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic',
    'starter.controllers',
    ... more modules here
])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.hide();
        }
    });
})
.... more code
```

EDIT:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
$ ionic build ios
$ ionic run ios
```

EDIT II: (Try with a fresh Project and iPhone Simulator)

```
$ ionic start testStatusBar tabs
$ cd testStatusBar/
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
$ vim www/js/app.js


Edit this:
if(window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  // StatusBar.styleDefault();
  StatusBar.hide();
}

$ vim www/index.html

add class="fullscreen" to the <body> element


$ ionic platform add ios
$ ionic build ios
$ ionic emulate ios
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. have you got any other references to the plugins in your app?

Comment: With some playing, and i'm not sure what was different, the status bar now is white text. the green battery is still visible against the white background, so this is not ideal, is this what you get?

Comment: After the splash screen, when the app is started, the status bar is completely hidden (no time, no battery etc etc)

Comment: No it's still just white text. I am seeing someone later who has used a few so I may be able to shed light then. For now all i think is I've done something wrong, but don't know what